# SAS PROC REPORT Conditional Output in a Column

Tags: sas, report, proc

I am trying to learn SAS and specifically PROC REPORT. I am using SASHELP.CARS dataset.

What I want to achieve in the 6th column of the output, labelled as 'Number of Cars > Mean(Invoice)' to compute number of cars whose Invoice is greater than the Group's mean of Invoice. I am using the code below.

```
PROC REPORT DATA=sashelp.CARS NOWD OUT=learning.MyFirstReport;
COLUMNS Type Origin INVOICE=Max_INVOICE INVOICE=Mean_Invoice 
INVOICE=Count_Invoice TEST DriveTrain;
DEFINE Type / Group 'Type of Car' CENTER;
DEFINE Origin / Group 'Origin of Car' CENTER;
DEFINE Max_Invoice / ANALYSIS MAX 'Max of Invoice';
DEFINE Mean_Invoice / ANALYSIS MEAN 'Mean of Invoice';
DEFINE Count_Invoice / ANALYSIS N FORMAT=5.0 'Total Number of Cars' center;
DEFINE DriveTrain / ACROSS 'Type of DriveTrain of Car';
DEFINE TEST / COMPUTED 'Number of Cars > Mean(Invoice)' center;
COMPUTE TEST;
     TEST=N(_c7_>Mean_Invoice);
ENDCOMP;
RUN;
```

The Output that I am getting is in the image below.

[Output of the above SAS code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tfdMZ.png)

I don't think that is the correct output since all the rows in the column show a value of 1. How do I get the desired output in the 6th column of the output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The non group columns are being defined analysis for computing aggregate statistics.  One way to achieve a count of a logical evaluation is to prep the data so that a SUM aggregation of an individual flag (0 or 1) is the count of positive assertions.

**Prepare**

```
proc sql;
  create view cars_v as
  select *
  , mean(invoice) as invoice_mean_over_type_origin
  , (invoice > calculated invoice_mean_over_type_origin) as flag_50
  from sashelp.cars
  group by type, origin
  ;
```

**Report**

```
PROC REPORT DATA=CARS_V OUT=work.MyFirstReport;
COLUMNS 
  Type 
  Origin 
  INVOICE/*=Max_INVOICE */
  INVOICE=INVOICE_use_2/*=Mean_Invoice */

  flag_50
  flag_50=flag_50_use_2

  flag_50_other
  DriveTrain
;
  DEFINE Type / Group 'Type of Car' CENTER;
  DEFINE Origin / Group 'Origin of Car' CENTER;
  DEFINE Invoice / ANALYSIS MAX 'Max of Invoice';
  DEFINE Invoice_use_2 / ANALYSIS MEAN 'Mean of Invoice';

  DEFINE flag_50 / analysis sum  'Number of Cars > Mean ( Invoice )' center;

  DEFINE flag_50_use_2 / noprint analysis N  ;
  * noprint makes a hidden column whose value is available to compute blocks;

  DEFINE flag_50_other / computed 'Number of Cars <= Mean ( Invoice )' center;
  DEFINE DriveTrain / ACROSS 'Type of DriveTrain of Car';

  compute flag_50_other;
    flag_50_other = flag_50_use_2 - flag_50.sum;
  endcomp;
RUN;
```

- In newer versions of SAS `NOWD` is a default option. New `Proc REPORT` code does not need to specified it explicitly.
- Reusing a variable such as `invoice=mean_invoice` is ok, but a future reader of the code might have some misunderstanding when seeing the `DEFINE Mean_Invoice / ANALYSIS MEAN 'Mean of Invoice';` line of code -- is the define for the *mean* or *the mean of a mean* 
  ?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I really appreciate it. I got similar answer in other forum as well (where I had asked the question @ https://communities.sas.com/t5/SAS-Procedures/SAS-PROC-REPORT-Conditional-Output-in-a-Column/td-p/496041). I guess the initial logic is same in both places where you are setting a column of flag. I am starting to like SAS. Thanks again.